# Problem with selecting elements with the same params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What i do wrong? I want to return every products which pass condition:

```
def show
    products = Product.select{|x| x[:category_id] == params[:id]}
    render json: products
end
```

When i write

```
def show
    products = Product.select{|x| x[:category_id] == 1}
    render json: products
end
```

it works why the first example doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you not using `Product.where(category_id: ...)`? The reason the first one doesn't work is probably because `params[:id]` is not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Using `.select` with a block will cause Rails to load every record on the table. Use `.where` as suggested by @Eyeslandic.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that there is mismatch in data type.

```rb
1=='1' #will be always false
1==1 #will be true
'1'=='1' #will be true as well
```

And also check for `nil` value from `params[:id]`

Please make sure to change as follows

```rb
def show
    products = Product.select{|x| x.category_id == params[:id].to_i}
    render json: products
end
```

OR

The best solution as suggested by @Eyeslandic is to use `.where` as it will not check for mismatch in data type. And also you don't have to take care of `nil` value from `params[:id]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a where to stop sql from loading all your products.

```
@products = Product.where('category_is = ?', params[:id])
```

The being said, if you are sticking to rails restful conventions, the fact you have a param called :id that is the category_id suggests you are on the category controller. So maybe consider changing your logic to:

```
@category = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:id])
```

you can then access products via

```
@category.products
```

or if your not interested in the category too much maybe

```
@products = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:id])&.products
```